# Is referencing parent(this) inside a child function bad practice?

Tags: javascript

**Context**

In a typical JavaScript OO class when you have for e.g.

```
function parent(){
     this.a = "parent";
     this.child = function(){
          console.log(this.a); //undefined
     }
}
```

Now I know that you can reference the parent **this** by using:

```
 var that = this;
```

**Question**

Is this considered good, bad or neutral practice? And I guess maybe guide me on things to look out for in terms of performance or possibly alternative methods.

Note: I have read some other stackoverflow question/answers but they are more requesting how to use it rather than what the issues are with using it, if any.

Comment: In your example I believe this refers to the global object.

Comment: @ Aiden: FWIW, "outer" and "inner" are the usual terms for this (e.g., the "outer scope" in this example being the scope of your `parent` function and the "inner scope" being the scope of your `child` function). Alnitak flagged this up in a comment on my answer, but I thought it deserved more prominent placement.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this considered good, bad or neutral practice?

It's completely normal practice. It's fundamental to how JavaScript works. As long as it's appropriate to the situation, there's nothing wrong with it.

---

***Subjective***:

Using `that` for this is a pet peeve of mine. It makes no sense whatsoever to call it `that`. It is, however, common practice. :-) I frequently use `self` and it's quite common (not as common as `that`). As pointed out in the comments, it *slightly* opens you to debugging hassles because `self` is a global on browsers (it's similar to `window`). Another one I common do is to pick a noun related to what the thing actually is, which adds semantic value. For instance, if `this` refers to a `Whatsit` instance, I might use `whatsit` or `theWhatsit`. Another suggestion is below is `_this` (with the underscore). A decent IDE will color that differently from `this`, reducing your odds of misreading it, but there's that concern.

But this is **purely** a style choice, and `that` is a choice a lot of people make.

Comment: worth pointing out though that the OP's usage of "parent" and "child" are not standard usage...

Comment: @Alnitak: Indeed. Probably best as a comment on the question, rather than part of an answer.

Comment: `self` is dangerous. It's never undefined in browser (because it's the `window` object) and one can easily stumble upon a hard–to-debug situation when you forget to assign it to `this`.

Comment: @katspaugh: In theory, yes. In practice, I've never once had an issue in years of using `self`. I'd be happy with an alternative if you have a non-`that` suggestion. :-) I tried `me` for a while but didn't like it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I just want to point out that it's not a matter of style. If anything could affect choosing an arbitrary name for a commonly used variable, one should avoid name conflicts.

Comment: hey guys :) thanks for replying really awesome, everyone changing stuff haha so var that = this is purely a reference correct? and if i am to use this regularly then there is no real risk of redundancy.

Comment: @katspaugh: Yes, it's an input into the naming equation.

Comment: @Aiden: If `this` is a reference (and it almost always is), then yes, after `that = this`, `that` will be a reference to the same thing `this` referred to when you did that assignment. (`this` can be a primitive [non-reference] in strict mode.)

Comment: I think its may good to abstract `this` with a underscore like `var _this = this`. Then its obvious i guess.

Comment: Absolutely agree that `self` and `that` are equally ambiguous, and therefore unhelpful. A semantic description is far better (ie `parent` — which actually describes what the variable is referring to).

Comment: @mrzmyr: Yeah. Not a fan of underscores, but it's a good idea.

Comment: @Barney above I took exception to the OP's use of "parent" terminology, because that's more commonly used for things such as tree structures (e.g. the DOM) and the OP's use is simply lexical closure where what is being referred to is normally called the "outer" scope.

Comment: @Alnitak doubly agreed — in context `parent` is actually probably very poor. More context for the function's actual function would be helpful…